# How do I get PDO to work on WAMP with PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, pdo

How do I get PDO to work on WAMP with PHP 5.4?
I have installed PHP 5.4 inside of WAMP (2.2d 32-bit). My PHP.ini file has it enabled (Inside of the 5.4 phpForApache.ini file). I downloaded the latest PHP 5.4 Thread Safe for windows.

But I can't get the PDO extension to work. Here is my php info file:

```
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" 
"--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" 
"--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" 
"--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-    sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" 
"--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-        sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" 
"--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet" 
"--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"


PDO drivers no value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article: http://www.bluefrog.ca/2012/03/adding-php-5-4-0-final-support-to-wampserver/

> Though you’ll now have support for 5.4, you’ll be missing some fancy extensions and features that you may have gotten used to on other
>   versions of PHP. These may include:
>
> ```
> Xdebug
> APC
> PDO drivers
> Curl
> etc…
> ```

I will suggest installing Apache 2, Mysql, PHP separately. And its working just fine.

Comment: But in there it says: You’ll need to enable what you want and tweak some settings in the php.ini to get the desired behavior.

Comment: The desired behavior does not mean the extensions.